# Calling profile from another class with Python/Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Having trouble calling the method `chrome_configuration` that comes from class `Profile`, I want to call that method on `TestBase` class:

```
class TestBase:

     driver = None

     def setup(self):
         Profile.chrome_configuration()


class Profile:

     driver = None

     def chrome_configuration(self):
         self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
         self.driver.set_window_size(1900, 1200)
         self.driver.maximize_window()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must instantiate the class or make the method static. Below are examples of each option.

```
#By initializing the profile class
class TestBase(object):

     driver = None

     profile = Profile() 

     def setup(self):
         profile.chrome_configuration()

#By making the method static
class Profile(object):

     driver = None

     @staticmethod
     def chrome_configuration(self):
         self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
         self.driver.set_window_size(1900, 1200)
         self.driver.maximize_window()
```

In addition, all your classes should always inherit from `object` in 2.x. It's called new-style classes.